# Disable GET functionality of WEB API token call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I developed an application using ASP.NET WEB API 2. The application is completed and in the process of having security review done on it, but one of the requirements is that any GET requests for login must be disabled.

We are making the call to the token action over POST, but the security team picked up that you can still make the same request with GET and that needs to be removed. I know the token call is one that is built into the whole OWIN/OAUTH system, but is it possible to configure it so that it will only accept POST requests and block GET?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into Katana project sources I can see that in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler` they have the following check:

```
if (Options.TokenEndpointPath.HasValue && Options.TokenEndpointPath == Request.Path)
{
    matchRequestContext.MatchesTokenEndpoint();
}
```

As you can see there is no additional check for HTTP METHOD. Therefore as one of the possible solution I can propose you to write your own middleware which is executing before authentication one and checks for the HTTP METHOD:

```
public class OnlyPostTokenMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private readonly OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions opts;

    public OnlyPostTokenMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions opts) : base(next)
    {
        this.opts = opts;
    }

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (opts.TokenEndpointPath.HasValue && opts.TokenEndpointPath == context.Request.Path && context.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            return Next.Invoke(context);
        }

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Not Found";
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("Not Found");
    }
}
```

then in Startup.cs you would have something similar to:

```
var authOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    Provider = Resolver.GetService<OAuthProvider>(),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
};

app.Use<OnlyPostTokenMiddleware>(authOptions);
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(authOptions);
```

Comment: Dude you are a legend. I just made a couple of minor changes. The invoke intercepts every request coming in, so the only request it was allowing was POST to "/token". So I just changed the invoke if check from context.Request.Method == "POST" to context.Request.Method != "POST" and then swapped the if statement return and the 3 lines below the if around thus it only blocks "/token" that is not "POST" the rest of requests it allows.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that my answer helped you. I believe that there is not much difference between your approach and the one described in my answer. Therefore I won't change it if you don't mind :)